# onBackPressed method showing for less than a second

Tags: android

I am using the above method to create something like an exit dialog for my application. The code works just fine but the alert dialog box only stays on screen for less than a second. Then it dissapears and the application closes without following my instructions. I have no idea why this is happening.

Thank you guyz in advance.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();

      DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which){
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                ganthem.stop();
                System.exit(0);
                break;

            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:

                dialog.cancel();

                break;
            }
        }
    };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Exit or not ?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
        .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();
    }
```

Comment: Removed `super` method. By default, `onBackPressed` will end your activity

Comment: Aprian gave the right answer.

Comment: Btw, don't use `System.exit(0);`, use `finish()` instead. Why? I don't know, but maybe Google knows.

Comment: @Aprian : **"Why? I don't know, but maybe Google knows."** - Because `System.exit(...)` is a generic Java method which doesn't understand the complexities of the Android `Activity` class and basically just terminates a VM and won't allow the `Activity` to go through its normal life-cycle methods of shutting down. To draw an analogy...open a text editor on your computer then type some text then pull the plug out of the computer...you'll lose the text - that's what `System.exit(...)` does. Using `finish()` on the other hand allows an `Activity` to save data etc (if written correctly).

Comment: @Aprian : I've posted an answer to the question which expands on your comment not to call the super method. Depending on the model, it might be better to do it but from a different place in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the advice to remove the call to `super.onBackPressed()`, for completeness I would simply recommend moving the call.

The comment from Aprian on your original question correctly answers why you're seeing the dialog for only a short time and the app is closing.

However...

Suppose you have two `Activity` classes such as...

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // Do something
    }
}

public class ActivityB extends ActivityA {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // Do something
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

In this case you will want to call through to `super.onBackPressed()` in the `onBackPressed()` method of `ActivityB`.

In the case of your code, it is not clear what your `Activity` extends but I would change the code as follows...

```
DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        switch (which){
        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
            ganthem.stop();
            MyActivity.this.onBackPressed();
            break;

        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
            dialog.cancel();
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

If your `Activity` extends the Android `Activity` class directly then (as Aprian commented) it will cause your `Activity` to 'finish' correctly. If, however, your `Activity` extends another `Activity` of your own which overrides `onBackPressed()` then the correct sequence of code will be executed.

One thing to be aware of though is if you have `Fragments` on the back stack in which case calling `onBackPressed()` on anything which directly extends the Android `Activity` class may simply cause the top `Fragment` to finish and the next to be popped from the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `super.onBackPressed();`.

Comment: You should explain a bit more your answer so that it is more complete.